# Display element of 2nd array whose suffix matched with 1st array

Tags: php, arrays, string, filtering

I have two arrays, i.e.:

```
array('ly', 'ful', 'ay')
```

and

```
array('beautiful', 'lovely', 'power')
```

I want to print the content of second array whose suffix matched with first array. i.e. the output should be `lovely`, `beautiful`.

How can I do this in PHP?

Comment: try some regex for this.

Comment: And you tried so far is ?

Comment: Does order matter? Is the output `['beautiful', 'lovely']` just as acceptable as `['lovely', 'beautiful']`?

Answer (score 3):

Try this

```
$suffix=array('ly','ful','ay');
$words = array('beautiful','lovely','power');
$finalarray=array();
foreach($words as $word)
{
    foreach($suffix as $suff)
    {
       $pattern = '/'.$suff.'$/';
       if(preg_match($pattern, $word))
       {
           $finalarray[]=$word;
       }
    }
}
print_r($finalarray);
```

You can test online on http://writecodeonline.com/php/

**Output**

```
Array ( [0] => beautiful [1] => lovely )
```

Answer (score 1):

This should give you what you want, assuming the order is not important in the resulting array:

```
$arr1 = ['ly', 'ful', 'ay'];
$arr2 = ['beautiful', 'lovely', 'power'];

$result = array_filter($arr2, function($word) use ($arr1){
    $word_length = strlen($word);
    return array_reduce($arr1, function($result, $suffix) use ($word, $word_length) {
        if($word_length > strlen($suffix))
            $result = $result || 0 === substr_compare($word, $suffix, -strlen($suffix), $word_length);
        return $result;
    }, false);
});

print_r($result);

/*
Array
(
    [0] => beautiful
    [1] => lovely
)
*/
```

[**See Demo**](http://ideone.com/8AofTu)

Answer (score 1):

Try to use [`array_filter()`](http://php.net/array-filter) with valid callback. In your case I suggest to look at [*regular expressions*](http://php.net/pcre) ([`preg_replace()`](http://php.net/preg-replace) or [`preg_match()`](http://php.net/preg-match)).

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: text/plain');

$a = array('beautiful','lovely','power');
$b = array('ly','ful','ay');

$filters  = array_map(function($filter){ return '/' . $filter . '$/'; }, $b);

$c = array_filter(
     $a,
     function($element)use($filters){ return $element != preg_replace($filters, '', $element); }
     );

var_dump($c);
?>
```

Shows:

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  string(9) "beautiful"
  [1]=>
  string(6) "lovely"
}
```

---

***UPDv1:***

More short and optimized version with [`preg_match()`](http://php.net/preg-match):

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: text/plain');

$a = array('beautiful','lovely','power');
$b = array('ly','ful','ay');

$filter  = '/^.*(' . implode('|', $b) . ')$/';

$c = array_filter(
     $a,
     function($element)use($filter){ return preg_match($filter, $element); }
     );

var_dump($c);
?>
```

Same output.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
$suffixes = array('ly','ful','ay');
$words = array('beautiful','lovely','power');

foreach($suffixes as $suffix){
    foreach($words as $word){
        if(strripos($word, $suffix) == strlen(str_replace($suffix, '', $word))){
            $results[] = $word;   
        }
    }
}

print_r($results);
```

You could definitely optimize this and make it shorter, but it's easy to understand and a good starting point.

Comment: `strripos($word, $suffix) == strlen(str_replace($suffix, '', $word))`, because just `strripos($word, $suffix)` will find suffix anywhere. `pfulower` was not filtered out.

Comment: hmm yeah. I guess you're right. Last night I tested it with `fullness` which didn't get filtered. Why would `fullness` be ignored but `pfulower` be selected?